# How to speed up R terra crop, resample, mask, and roll functions?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, raster, terra

I have many large rasters from WorldClim, with monthly precipitation data from 1985 to 2018, totalling 408 rasters. I'd like to obtain total annual precipitation for one desired area for these 34 years.

I also need to use resample and add the precipitation data as a new layer to a SpatRaster. This SpatRaster has forest age for desired forests in this area of interest - the rest is a lot of NAs.

For this, I am:

- downloading the data (for the entire world)
- cropping to desired area
- resampling to the origin and resolution of the rest of my dataset
- masking to the forest age SpatRaster (to remove unnecessary information, outside of the desired forests)
- using terra::roll to get the sum for every 12 layers, reducing the 408-layer raster to 34 layers, one for each year.

```
forest_age <- rast(ncol=16055, nrow=31744, xmin=-48.32658, xmax=-43.99984, ymin=-3.282444, ymax=5.272392 )
i <- sample(ncell(forest_age), 0.85*ncell(forest_age))
forest_age[i] <- NA

# get the precipitation data
yr1 <- rast(ncol=8640, nrow=4320, xmin=-180, xmax=180, ymin=-90, ymax=90)
raster_clim <- lapply(1:120, function(i) setValues(yr1,runif(ncell(yr1))))

e <- ext(forest_age)
raster_clim_cropped <- lapply(raster_clim, crop, e)
raster_clim_resampled <- lapply(raster_clim_cropped, resample, forest_age, method='near')
raster_clim_masked <- lapply(raster_clim_resampled, mask, forest_age)

rstr <- rast(raster_clim_masked)

# processes the dataframes into yearly climate data
yearly <- terra::roll(rstr, 12, "sum", type="to")
```

This is taking too many hours. I tried paralellizing with mclapply, with no success (Error: external pointer is not valid).

raster_clim takes a couple minutes to be generated with the 408 rasters, so I reproduced the example with only 10 years (120 rasters).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the most important issue that slows things down is that you use `lapply` where there is no need for it. Furthermore, the order of operations matters. The earlier you reduce the number of layers, the faster things will go. In this case, I would first use `crop` and then compute the yearly sum.

It is an error to use `roll` for summation. That gets you the rolling sum, whereas you want simple yearly sums. You can use `tapp` for that.

I do not understand why you would use nearest-neighbor resampling with continuous data.

I would do:

```
rc <- crop(raster_clim, e)
ry <- tapp(rc, rep(1:12, each=12), "sum")
rs <- resample(ry, forest_age)
rm <- mask(rs, forest_age)
```

Comment: Perfect! I had just found a way to reduce the time by writing a 10-line for loop to do what you did there with tapp. the code ran, but this is much simpler. thanks a lot!